# how to make the same app act differently for different pages in facebook

Tags: facebook

I have a private app. My app is just a link to open the chatpopup in a different window. The anchor tag with the chat url is what is in the app. You can see the app here.
https://www.facebook.com/247guatemala/app_1498840933690512.

With the same design am planning to add the same app to different page. But my app should have a different url link in the anchor tag.

Is there any way to identify in which page my app is running. If i know that i can modify my anchor tag based on that via javascript.

Comment: The page id is passed in the signed request to you

Answer (score 0):

For certain types of apps, a signed request is passed to the app which contains some additional fields of information, even before Permissions have been requested. You can find detail information in this doc:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request